# How does Google Maps´ "optimizeWaypoints" solve Travelling Salesmen?

Tags: java, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, heuristics, traveling-salesman

I want to solve a Travelling Salesman Problem like Google Maps does in its `DirectionsRequest` with `request.setOptimizeWaypoints(true);`. It orders some Waypoints in a route so that the travelling-costs are minimal.

My question: Does anybody know which algorithm stands behind it? Any heuristic? Could not find any information by google, so far.

I informed myself and found a lot of insertion-heuristics, nearest neighbour, and so on... Or is it an exact solution procedure?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Wikipedia page on the [Travelling Salesman Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem) references a number of algorithms for finding solutions.  (But unless `N` is small, avoid the "exact" algorithms!)

According to [this post](https://plus.google.com/+ResearchatGoogle/posts/fcDYLZjHnRj) from a Google employee, the source code for the Googles route calculation algorithms is available here:

- http://code.google.com/p/or-tools/source/browse/trunk/examples/cpp/tsp.cc
- http://code.google.com/p/or-tools/source/browse/trunk/src/constraint_solver/routing.h

... but it is not entirely clear if this is the "production" code for Google Maps.

From a comment in the source code:

```
// Solving the vehicle routing problems is mainly done using approximate methods
// (namely local search,
// cf. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_search_(optimization)), potentially
// combined with exact techniques based on dynamic programming and exhaustive
// tree search.
```

---

This general issue (Google Maps vs TSP) is also discussed in various other SO questions.

References:

- [Optimal map routing with Google Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337607/optimal-map-routing-with-google-maps)
- [Travelling Salesman with Google Maps API or any other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17308805/travelling-salesman-with-google-maps-api-or-any-other)
- [What is a practical solution to the Travelling Salesman prblem, using Google Maps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7736674/what-is-a-practical-solution-to-the-travelling-salesman-prblem-using-google-map)

Comment: So it seems to me, concerning local search g-maps it using some algorithms like simulated annealing / tabu search. Thank you Stephen.